# How to log information from inside <CFScript>

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, lucee

I am learning to use `<cfscript>`.

Is there any way I can log some messages or values inside the <`cfscript>`?

like outside `<cfscript>` I can use `<cflog>`, Is there any way or Tag something like that, i can use to print the messages in log file inside >

Thanks

Comment: Echoing Terry Ryan's comment CF9 has a much more complete cfscript implementation.

Comment: Careful! the Open Blue Dragon ColdFusion implementation doesn't offer cfscript, so if you use it you're tied to Adobe.

Comment: @Ollie Jones, no, he is not. He can use Railo, which has full-script CFC support.

Comment: @OllieJones: yeah it does. Just tested on OpenBD 3.0

Comment: @CFUser, given you're getting differing answers for different CFML engines, it might help if you tag this with the correct engine / version?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

ColdFusion 9 added the "writeLog" function which allows you to do this. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS48D04B65-0694-44e9-9E35-F9D7C9152B6C.html

Comment: Knew I'd seen something in CF9... typically couldn't see it when I looked. Thanks for the reminder Terry.

Answer (score 5):

In Lucee/Railo you can use cflog in script by removing the angular brackets and the "cf" prefix, so you can write

```
<cfscript>
  log text="some text" file="logfilename" type="information";
</cfscript>
```

this is equivalent to

```
<cflog text="some text" file="logfilename" type="information">
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately on versions of ColdFusion prior to CF9 there isn't.  However, what you can do is map a UDF to cflog:

```
<cffunction name="doCFLog">
   <cflog attributeCollection="#arguments#">
</cffunction>
```

inside your cfscript call the doCFLog function with the same attributes as you would cflog

eg. doCFLog(text='sometext', type='warning',application='yes', file='mylog');

Note: its not a good idea to call your methods/udf etc the same name as an existing function or tag, hence not calling the function "cflog" or "log"

Comment: Doesn't it have to be: <cflog attributeCollection="#arguments#">?

Comment: It didn't work for me without using # in ColdFusion 8.  I'm not sure when/why that format is required, but hopefully it'll help someone else if they had the problem I did...

Comment: Yeah, the *quotes* are optional, but the pound-signs are required (all versions of ColdFusion, and at least Railo 4.1 and OpenBD 3.0). I've tweaked the code above accordingly.